# Jquery mobile list view with checkbox phonegap on Lollipop device

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, checkbox, jquery-mobile-listview

I am building a jquery mobile list view by dynamically adding list elements inside a list view using the below code.  The below code works fine and it displayed the list view with the checkbox as expected.  But the problem is when I launch in the mobile and try to scroll the listview the checkbox of the corresponding list item that was touched gets selected which I dont want.

I.e, the checkbox should be selected only if the checkbox is touched and not the list item.  How can I do that?

```
$('#ul_history_list').append('<li>' +
    '<a href="#" style="padding:0px !important; margin:0px !important;">' +
      '<label style="margin:0px !important; border:0px !important;"' +
        '<input name="chk_history" id="chk_history" type="checkbox" />' +
        '<div>' +
          '<h3>'+header+'</h3>' +
          '<p>'+message+'</p>' +
          '<p class="ui-li-aside"><i>Sent</i></p>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</label>' +
    '</a>' +
    '<a href="#pg_history-view"  class="nav-container" ></a>'+
    '</li>');
  });
$("input[name=chk_history]").checkboxradio();
$('#ul_history_list').listview('refresh');
```

I created a jsfiddle.  I think the problem is when I click the list item the checkbox is getting selected.  What I need is the check should select only if the checkbox is clicked.

[Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/z52y9f27/1/)

Update: I noticed that this problem is only after building the android APK using phonegap build and deployed on an android Lollipop device.